# SQL : Get common values of a table column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table. I want to fetch common values of a column of that table in an html php page. If a column contains A, B, A, C, I want to fetch A in a php page through query.

Comment: common or duplicate ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
select col
from your_table
group by col
having count(*) > 1
```